# Javascript menubar=no not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I have this js

```
var option= "location=no";
    option+= ",toolbar=no";
    option+= ",menubar=no";
    option+= ",status=no";
    option+= ",scrollbars=yes";
    option+= ",resizable=yes";
    option+= ",top=35";
    option+= ",left=35";
    option+= ",width=900";
    option+= ",height=675";
    window.open(pdfurl, "Preview", option);
```

Now this works fine in IE8, IE9. When I tested this in IE10, it was still showing the menubar(it was not executing any options..it just pops up a window) and Also I am getting the exception URL not found in the popup.Strange part is it works fine in IE8 and IE9

Can someone help me here

Comment: There's an setting in Internet Options | Security | Internet Zone, where you can give web pages a privilege to open windows witout limiting size or position. Also there's an option for showing pop-ups without addressbar and status bar. You've to check, if the URL is correct also in IE10.

Comment: I am using the same URL in IE8 and IE9 also .It works fine there.

Comment: How are you constructing the URL? Maybe `pdfurl` is not what you think in IE10?